# SQL*Net message from client too important

Tags: java, oracle, azure, redhat

It is not easy to describe my problem but I will try. We noticed a slow processing problem with the database when migrating an application from a current VM named VM1 (RedHat 7.9, Java 8, Tomcat, Apache in a DC data center) to a new VM named VM2 (RedHat 8.7, more performance on the Azure platform).

The database is Oracle 19c on a RedHat 7.9 (named VM_DB) on the DC.

Following this observation, I made a small Java program, which launches on the 2 VMs, VM1 and VM2, and we discovered the time "SQL*Net message from client" is too large on VM2 compared to VM1 (same driver ojdbc8-19.18.0.0.jar).

[image: VM1]

[image: VM2]

We looked on the network side, database and found nothing for the moment. Have you had any ideas or experiences on this subject?

my **test** app

```
        int nLoop = 100;
        long time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Connection con=null;
        //---------------- connection 1 ---------------         
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,pwd); 
        
        //---------------- connection 2 ---------------
        /*
        PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

        pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
        pds.setURL(url); //"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
        pds.setUser(usr);
        pds.setPassword(pwd);
        pds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        pds.setMinPoolSize(5);
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(25);
        //pds.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        //pds.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        //pds.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true)
        
        
        con = pds.getConnection();
        */
        
        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("T1 - connection :"+ ((time1-time0)));
        
        //step3 create the statement object  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        
        for(int t=0; t < nLoop; t++) {
            
            System.out.println("------- loop " + t + "-------");
    
            //step4 execute query
            time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("T2 - executeQuery :"+ ((time2-time1)));
    
            ResultSetMetaData MetaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int nbColumn = (MetaData != null) ? MetaData.getColumnCount() : 1;
            //System.out.println("nombreCol :"+ nbColumn);
            // test fetch without display
            while (rs.next()) {
                for(int i = 0; i < nbColumn; i++) {
                    String temp = rs.getString(1+i);
                    if (temp != null) {;} else {;};
                }
            }
            rs.close();
            long time3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("T3 - fetch without display :"+ ((time3-time2)));
            
            // test fetch avec display
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            int nb = 0;
            time3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (rs.next()) {
                nb++;
                for(int i = 0; i < nbColumn; i++) {
                    String temp = rs.getString(1+i);
                    System.out.println(temp);
                    //if (temp != null) {;} else {;};
                }
            }
            rs.close();
            long time4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("T4 - fetch avec display :"+ ((time4-time3)) + ", nb:" + nb);
        }       
        long time5 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total :"+ (time5-time0));
        
        //step5 close the connection object  
        con.close();
        
        // ---- JVM ---
        System.out.println(" ---- JVM ---- ");
        // get a RuntimeMXBean reference
        RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

        // get the jvm's input arguments as a list of strings
        List<String> listOfArguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();
        
        // print the arguments using my logger
        listOfArguments.forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
            //logger.log(s"ARG: $a")
        });
```

Comment: "SQL*NET message from client" is usually harmless. It means DB session is just blocked, waiting for another job to work on. The more idle connections you have the more time will be spent on this event. If your both environments have same connection pool sizes, try to analyze JVM on application side.

Comment: i tried get parameters of JVM (based on https://alvinalexander.com/java/how-see-jvm-parameters-arguments-from-running-java-application/) there is nothing on 2 VMs.

Comment: "* from client" is an idle wait. It's what Oracle registers when your session is doing *nothing* because there's nothing to do. The more important question is how much elapsed time are you experiencing end-to-end, and what percent of that is the 2 to 3 seconds reported in your tkprof output ? If it's a tiny percentage, your issue is not in the database at all.

Comment: i have no idea, i didn't say the pb is caused by the base. FYI, the run time of my app test on VM2 is ~ 10 times more than that on VM1

Comment: that is either network connectivity issue or how application is processing rows returned by query: you app issued 200 queries, each query returned 6000 rows, application fetched those rows in 600 fetches (default fetch size in ojdbc is 10), "SQL*Net message from client" is a time DB was waiting for the next fetch command, all that time oracle connection was busy serving app request.

Comment: i added my test app in my post. As said, no problem / no overload on the network. And with the same test, the is no pb with VM1 on DC

Comment: Being on the cloud is about paying stellar bills for old-laptop performances. There is nothing to be surprised here. Work as intended.